# Downloading file from custom element action

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to download a CSV file from a custom created element action

Here's the performAction function

```
    public function performAction(ElementCriteriaModel $criteria) {
        $contents = 'row1column1,row2column2'.PHP_EOL.'row2column1,row2column2'.PHP_EOL;

        craft()->request->sendFile('export.csv', $contents, array('forceDownload' => true), false);

        return true;  
    }
```

No error is thrown, the code passes right through the function. When I check the craft logs, there's no sign of any error

And yet, there's no download occuring. When I try this same code in a controller or a service, it works just fine. But in this element action class, nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because those element actions happen over an AJAX and you have to [jump through a few hoops](https://www.google.com/search?q=download%20a%20file%20to%20browser%20over%20ajax) to send a file to the browser over an AJAX request.

Answer (score 3):

Element actions take place over AJAX requests, so the `performAction` method will not work as you are expecting.

Here's how I solved it in Craft 3.

In the element action class, create a redirect to a controller action in the `activate` setting of the `ElementActionTrigger`:

```php
public function getTriggerHtml()
{
    $type = Json::encode(static::class);

    $js = <<<EOD
(function()
{
var trigger = new Craft.ElementActionTrigger({
    type: {$type},
    activate: function() {
        Craft.redirectTo(Craft.getActionUrl('my-plugin/my-controller/say-hello'));
    }
});
})();
EOD;

    Craft::$app->getView()->registerJs($js);

    return null;
}
```

Then perform the download in the controller:

```php
public function actionSayHello(): Response
{
    return Craft::$app->getResponse()->sendContentAsFile('Hello!', 'hello.pdf', [
        'mimeType' => 'application/pdf'
    ]);
}
```

You'll usually want to do something with the selected elements, which you can do by joining the selected element IDs:

```php
public function getTriggerHtml()
{
    $type = Json::encode(static::class);

    $js = <<<EOD
(function()
{
var trigger = new Craft.ElementActionTrigger({
    type: {$type},
    activate: function(\$selectedItems) {
        Craft.redirectTo(Craft.getActionUrl('my-plugin/my-controller/say-hello', 'elementIds=' + Craft.elementIndex.getSelectedElementIds().join('|')));
    }
});
})();
EOD;

    Craft::$app->getView()->registerJs($js);

    return null;
}
```

You can then explode the `elementIds` in the controller:

```php
public function actionSayHello(): Response
{
    $elementIds = Craft::$app->getRequest()->getRequiredParam('elementIds');
    $elementIds = explode('|', $elementIds);

    // Do something with elementIds

    return Craft::$app->getResponse()->sendContentAsFile('Hello!', 'hello.pdf', [
        'mimeType' => 'application/pdf'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant solution - I just implemented this in a module for my use-case and it worked a treat!